# How to amend an element within an object in a list?

Tags: python

I'm sure this is a really simple question but I'm having difficulty amending an element within a singular object within a list of objects. I have an object called volunteer set up:

```
#Create the volunteer class
class Volunteer():
    consecutiveDaysOff = 0
    totalDaysOff = 0
    locWorked = []
    schedule = []

    def __init__(self, employeeId):
        self.employeeId = employeeId

    def updateSchedule(self,location):
        self.schedule.append(location)

    def newDayOff(self):
        self.totalDaysOff =+1
        self.consecutiveDaysOff =+ 1
        self.schedule.insert(0,0)
```

And I have a list of volunteers set up:

```
v1 = Volunteer(1)
v2 = Volunteer(2)
v3 = Volunteer(3)
volunteerList = [v1,v2,v3]
```

I want to run the newDayOff() on just one element of the list using: volunteerList[0].newDayOff()

but every time I do it runs newdayoff() on every instance of Volunteer in the list. What is the correct way to to this?

```
import csv

#Create the volunteer class
class Volunteer():
    consecutiveDaysOff = 0
    totalDaysOff = 0
    locWorked = []
    schedule = []

    def __init__(self, employeeId):
        self.employeeId = employeeId

    def updateSchedule(self,location):
        self.schedule.append(location)

    def newDayOff(self):
        self.totalDaysOff =+1
        self.consecutiveDaysOff =+ 1
        self.schedule.insert(0,0)


# Test Variables
v1 = Volunteer(1)
v2 = Volunteer(2)
v3 = Volunteer(3)
v2.consecutiveDaysOff = 1
v1.totalDaysOff = 1
v2.totalDaysOff = 3
v3.totalDaysOff = 4

numVolunteers = 3
location = [1]
numLocation = 1


volunteerList = [v1,v2,v3]

#test inputs


#Take inputs

# try:
#     days = int(input("How many days are in the month? ") )
# except ValueError:
#     print("Invalid Input... Please Restart Program")
#     exit()
#
# try:
#     numVolunteers = input("How many volunteers are there? ")
# except ValueError:
#     print("Invalid Input... Please Restart Program")
#     exit()

# try:
#     location = input("What are the locations? (Should be numbers separated by ',')")
#
#     if location == "":
#         print("Locations were not entered.")
#         exit()
#
#     numLocation = 1
#     for i in range(0,len(location)):
#         if location[i] == ',':
#             numLocation = numLocation + 1
#
#     location = location.replace(" ", "")
#     location = location.split(',')
#     location = list(map(int, location))
#
# except ValueError:
#     print("Invalid Input... Please Restart Program")
#     exit()

#create the volunteer list
def createVolunteerList():
    for i in range(0,numVolunteers):
        volunteerList.append(Volunteer(i))

def sortArrayByConsecDaysOff():
    for i in range(0,len(volunteerList)):
        for j in range(0,len(volunteerList)):
            if volunteerList[i].consecutiveDaysOff > volunteerList[j].consecutiveDaysOff:
                volunteerList[i],volunteerList[j] = volunteerList[j],volunteerList[i]

def sortArrayByTotalDaysOff():
    for i in range(0,len(volunteerList)):
        for j in range(0,len(volunteerList)):
            if volunteerList[i].totalDaysOff < volunteerList[j].totalDaysOff:
                volunteerList[i], volunteerList[j] = volunteerList[j], volunteerList[i]

def printVolunteer():
    for i in range(0,len(volunteerList)):
        v = volunteerList[i]
        print(v.employeeId, " " ,v.consecutiveDaysOff, " " ,v.totalDaysOff, " " , v.locWorked, " ", v.schedule, "\n")

def assignDaysOff():
    # Define number of days off that can be taken that day
    remainingDaysOff = numVolunteers - numLocation


    # Loop through volunteers to give weekends to those that have had one consecutive day off.
    for i in range(0, len(volunteerList)):
        if volunteerList[i].consecutiveDaysOff == 1 and remainingDaysOff > 0:
            volunteerList[i].newDayOff()
            remainingDaysOff = remainingDaysOff - 1


    sortArrayByTotalDaysOff()
    # Loop through volunteers to assign weekends to those with the fewest days off so far.
    for i in range(0, len(volunteerList)):
        if remainingDaysOff > 0 and not volunteerList[i]:
            volunteerList[i].newDayOff()
            remainingDaysOff = remainingDaysOff - 1

printVolunteer()
volunteerList[0].newDayOff()
printVolunteer()
```

Comment: Unless you have a shared state somewhere I'm not seeing, I can't see this code causing that behavior.

Comment: This code seems to fail outright since you haven't specified a constructor that takes an argument. This code won't run, so I'm not sure how you're even testing it.

Comment: It looks like the problem could be with your instantiation of the properties. Try setting the properties in the class's `__init__` method.

Comment: I copy/pasted the entirety of the code I've written so far and the test case I'm using.

Comment: Last I checked, executable code snippets on SO don't work for python only javascript.

Comment: @BrianCain reformatted.

Comment: Another problem is `self.totalDaysOff =+1` - this is equivalent to `self.totalDaysOff = +1`, which in turn is equivalent to `self.totalDaysOff = 1`; I believe you wanted `self.totalDaysOff += 1`

Comment: Yup! Caught that about 30 min after I posted this. Thanks for the debut help @Blotosmetek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
class Volunteer():
    consecutiveDaysOff = 0
    totalDaysOff = 0
    locWorked = []
    schedule = []
```

to this:

```
class Volunteer():
    consecutiveDaysOff = 0
    totalDaysOff = 0
    def __init__(self):
        self.locWorked = list()
        self.schedule = list()
```

Your code is using the same instance of the list in every instance of your  Volunteer object.

Comment: This did not fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
> class Volunteer():
>     consecutiveDaysOff = 0
>     totalDaysOff = 0
>     locWorked = []
>     schedule = []
> 
>     def newDayOff(self):
>         self.totalDaysOff =+1
>         self.consecutiveDaysOff =+ 1
>         self.schedule.insert(0,0)
```

To

```
> class Volunteer():
>     def __init__(self):
>         self.consecutiveDaysOff = 0
>         self.totalDaysOff = 0
>         self.locWorked = []
>         self.schedule = []
> 
>     def newDayOff(self):
>         self.totalDaysOff =+1
>         self.consecutiveDaysOff =+ 1
>         self.schedule.insert(0,0)
```

**This should solve the issue..**